# In jQuery unable to unbind an added function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a function to an element. Later I'm trying to remove that function. It's not working in jQuery.

```
var myFunction=function(element){
   $(element).animate({
      /* Some Code in here */
   });
   myFunction(element); // I want in a loop
}

/* No issues with the function */

/* binding this function in another place */
$(otherElement).on('focus', myFunction); 

/* In another location I want to off the focus on the element */
$(otherElement).on('focus'); --> This is not working. My expectation is the animation to be stopped.
```

I have tried with live/die and bind/unbind too, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it's just an argument error.

`var myFunction=function(element){` ---> you just expect an dom element as argument. But `$(otherElement).on('focus', myFunction);`, what is passed to `myFunction` is a jQuery Event object, not dom element.

So, try this:

```
$(otherElement).on('focus', function(ev/*this is event, not element*/) {
    myFunction(this);
});
```

And if you want to unbind event, just use `$(otherElement).off('focus');`

Comment: Thanks @creeper. The issue looks like too much recursion exception throws internally for the attached functions. So unbinding is not working on the element. I think I need to find another approach for this.

Comment: @Siva what you think is right. Call `animation` recursively is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var myFunction = function(element) {
  var $element = $(element).animate({
    height: 'toggle'
  }, {
    done: function() {
      var flag = $element.data('stopAnimation');
      if (flag) {
        $element.removeData('stopAnimation');
        return;
      }
      myFunction(element);
    }
  });
  // I want in a loop
}

$('#otherElement').on('focus', function() {
  myFunction($('#element'))
});

$('#otherElement').on('blur', function() {
  $('#element').stop(true, true).data('stopAnimation', true);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="otherElement" />
<div id="element">element</div>
```

Note: I don't know whether it is the optimal solution